# Add a disabled field to a checkbox if a user has checked a certain amount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React to create a form, the form consists of one main form component, a child component that holds values for checkboxes, and then a generic checkbox component that I can reuse.

I am attempting to disable my checkboxes if my user has clicked 5, however, I keep receiving the error that isDisabled is not a function, and my app crashes.

Here is my child component that holds the checkbox component

```
export default class Features extends Component {
    state = {
        features: [
            {id: 1, value: "analytics", label: "Analytics", checked: false},
            {id: 2, value: "breakout_rooms", label: "Breakout Rooms", checked: false},
            {id: 3, value: "custom_branding", label: "Custom Branding", checked: false},
            {id: 4, value: "expo_and_vendor_booths", label: "Expo & Vendor Booths", checked: false},
            {id: 5, value: "live_streaming", label: "Live Streaming", checked: false},
            {id: 6, value: "local_time_zone_support", label: "Timezone Support", checked: false},
        ]
    }

    isDisabled = id => {
        return(
            this.props.features > 5
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <h4 className="ui centered question-header text-center">KEY FEATURES</h4>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row xs="4">
                    {
                        this.state.features.map((feature) => {
                            return (
                                <Checkbox name="key_features" key={feature.value}
                                          disabled={this.isDisabled()} handleChange={this.props.handleChange} {...feature} />
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </Row>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And here is my checkbox component

```
const Checkbox = (props) => {
    return (
        <Col>
            <div className="switch">
                <input id={props.value} name={props.name} disabled={props.disabled(props.value)} type="checkbox" value={props.value} className="visually-hidden" onChange={props.handleChange}/>
                <label htmlFor={props.value} className="switch-label checkbox-label text-center">{props.label}</label>
            </div>
        </Col>
    )
}

export default Checkbox
```

I'm very new to React and can't see why it won't let me pass the isDisabled down into my component. Is there a better way to do this kind of form validation?

Comment: whats the the value of features which is passed as props and in isDisabled function you are passing a id param which is never used, can you explain this part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count how many features are checked, you have to change this:

```
this.props.features > 5
```

To something like this:

```
this.props.features.filter(feature => feature.checked).length >= 5
```

Also, there's no reason to use a method for `isDisabled`. You could calculate it once in the render function, for example.

```
render() { 
  const fiveChecked = this.props.features.filter(feature => feature.checked).length >= 5

  ...

  <Checkbox disabled={fiveChecked && !feature.checked}
```